# In Symfony how to set default values to sfWidgetFormDateRange from action

Tags: symfony1

In Symfony how to set default values to sfWidgetFormDateRange from action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have to do the following:

```
$form->setDefault('field_name', array('from' => 'yesterday', 'to' => '+10 years'))
```

These `yesterday` and `+10 years` chants actually are anything suitable for `strtotime` function. Also, you could pass explicit dates without casting any magic:

```
$form->setDefault('field_name', array('from' => array('month' => 10, 'day' => 12, 'year' => 1984), 'to' => '+10 years'))
```